# Deadlifts are tiring me out faster than squats and bench press?

Tags: weightlifting, strength, deadlifts, endurance, powerlifting

I am squatting more than I deadlift but yet after as little as 5 lifts of deads I feel tired. I can cruise on the bench all day and it takes over an hour to get tired, and nearly the same with the squat. What is going on?

Comment: "5 lifts" = 5 sets or 5 reps? What kind of weight (or proportions of bodyweight) are we talking about here?

Comment: Talking about 5 reps Dave

Comment: What about intensity (percent of your 1rm)? Are your deadlifts closer to your max than everything else?

Comment: If your squat is more than your deadlift ***consistently*** , you need to either **check your squat/deadlift form** or ***you need to increase your deadlift weights.*** Your deadlift should be more than your squat.

Comment: You bench for an hour?

Comment: Kneel before zod, I squat 300 and deadlift 135...

Comment: Full squat (at least parallel) 300? And you only deadlift 135? Not possible. You are doing something wrong like @Kneel-Before-ZOD has stated.

Comment: Yes I love doing the bench press, and why is it impossible for me to squat 300 and deadlift 135. I hate deadlifts and rarely ever do them, while I squat every other day.

Comment: The only reason I am doing deadlifts right now is because my new workout buddy makes me do them.

Comment: Well, your legs are obviously capable of lifting the weight (as evidenced by the squats), so I'm going to assume that you have relatively weak grip strength which might be limiting your ability to deadlift. Or perhaps, since you don't like deadlifting, you're subconsciously convincing yourself that you can't do them as well / better than your other lifts.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, bench is going to exhaust you less because less muscle is being used.  This means it makes a smaller metabolic impact.
Also, if your deadlift is lower than your squat it isn't the end of the world, it just means you have a strength imbalance.
Deadlifts can exhaust you faster for many reasons.  It could be form issues, it could be that you are under-recovering (because deadlifts take longer to recover from than other exercises), or a lack of muscular endurance.

To correct this I would suggest spending a bit more time on deadlifts than you were before.  Increase the weight when you feel comfortable.  Focus on what you are bad at, in this case, high rep sets.  Do sets of 8.  Keep plugging away and come back if you see no change.

Answer (score 1):

My top three guesses:

1. You don't squat right.  You go down to about 60 degrees and call it a rep.  When you deadlift you are beyond the point where your squat ends.
2. You haven't done enough deadlifts.  It will take a few months of doing a lift before your helper muscles adjust.  A person never doing deadlifts can't just naturally deadlift more if they haven't done them.  Some people may take a few weeks, some a few months.
3. You don't like doing them.  Your attitude towards the lift decreases your adrenaline and you feel tired faster.